# Where is my kseg0_boot_mem? (PIC32)

Tags: pic, bootloader

I'm developing my bootloader based on [AN1388](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en554836). My bootloader is working pretty well.

I'm having problem with my app code. When I try to generate the hex code, seems there isn't "C startup code". My .map file says kseg0_boot_mem used is 0.

So I've tried to compile the demo app that came together with [AN1388](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en554836) "as is". It happens the same. But the pre-compiled hex in this example is correct. It has the kseg0_boot_mem in the hex.

So, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I'm using C32 v2.00 and the [AN1388](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en554836) was compiled with C32 v1.11.

Comment: I can't remember the specifics (haven't used a PIC32 with C32 for a little while) but have you got the linker script set up correctly? The startup code is probably referencing the C018.o file IIRC.

Comment: Are you getting a linker or compiler error? What exactly is the error if you are getting one?

Answer (score 1):

In MPLAB IDE check your build options -> directories to make sure that the Library Search path is set correctly. I believe this directory is where the linker loads the C startup code from.